# Поиск запущенного процесса

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Подскажите winapi функцию, которая искала бы среди запущенных процессов, например calc.exe.
Желательно готовый рабочий код, т.к. winapi для меня темный лес.

Comment: Именно процесс или окно? (HWND?)

Comment: Можно и окно. А окна проще искать, чем процессы?

Comment: После того, как найдете процесс, что требуется с ним сделать?

Comment: [Process Walking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684887(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Как подсказывает MSDN - например, с помощью [`EnumProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), например, вот так:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>

// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1

void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                   PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                   FALSE, processID );

    // Get the process name.

    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
             &cbNeeded) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                               sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }

    // Print the process name and identifier.

    _tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );

    // Release the handle to the process.

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( void )
{
    // Get the list of process identifiers.

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }


    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the name and process identifier for each process.

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
        {
            PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CreateToolhelp32Snapshot + Process32First + Process32Next + CloseHandle.
Отличие от EnumProcesses - больше информации о процессе получается в результате вызова API